# Refresh html canvas without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have a bouncing ball simulation that is coded with javascript and html. I need to update some of the variables (Gravity and Bounce factor) by inputting the values in a text box then click on a button to refresh the canvas and bounce the ball with new parameters. Heres my code.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var W = 1300,
  H = 450;

canvas.height = H;
canvas.width = W;

var ball = {},
  gravity = 0.2,
  bounceFactor = 0.7;

$('#update').click(function() {
  gravity = document.getElementById('grav').value;
  bounceFactor = document.getElementById('bounce').value;
  document.getElementById('setgrav').value = gravity;
  document.getElementById('setbounce').value = bounceFactor;
  update();
  setInterval(update, 1000 / 60);
});

ball = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  radius: 15,
  color: "red",
  // Velocity components
  vx: 2,
  vy: 1,
  draw: function() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  }
};

function clearCanvas() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);
}

function update() {
  clearCanvas();
  ball.draw();

  ball.y += ball.vy;
  ball.x += ball.vx;
  ball.vy += gravity;

  if (ball.y + ball.radius > H) {
    ball.y = H - ball.radius;
    ball.vy *= -bounceFactor;
  }
}

setInterval(update, 1000 / 60);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  Gravity
  <input type="text" name="grav" id="grav" value="" />
  <p>
    Bounce
    <input type="text" name="bounce" id="bounce" value="" />
    <p>
      Set Gravity
      <input type="text" name="setgrav" id="setgrav" value="" />
      <p>
        Set Bounce
        <input type="text" name="setbounce" id="setbounce" value="" />
        <p>

</form>
<button id="update">Update</button>
<canvas id="canvas" style="display:block;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    margin:50px auto;">

</canvas>
```

Its not working. When i click update. the Canvas goes blank. What im i doing wrong? Thanks

UPDATED QUESTION:

What if i needed to use an image for the ball instead of drawing the ball using Javascript?

Comment: why are people still mixing `$('#')` and `document.getElementById`? Use jQuery or do not use it, but please dont mix stuff. Makes it less readable!

Comment: Sorry @Alex, still a noob. Will improve my practices :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of assigning the actual value which is string, assign the value parsed as float into the variables.

```
gravity = parseFloat(document.getElementById('setgrav').value);
bounceFactor = parseFloat(document.getElementById('setbounce').value);
```

Now, whenever you click update, the values will be updated. I am assuming that the elements having `set` in their ids are the ones used to set the values of gravity and bounce.

Comment: Actually no, the elements with 'set' are just ued to confirm the values have been picked, but hey, thanks it worked partially. it updates the values as the ball continues bouncing. Im guessing i shall have to recode to reset the ball when i click update

Answer (score 1):

Thanks For the help @Akash, your solution helped out. It updated the values but i also had to reset the balls attributes for it to start bouncing from the beginning once i click update. Heres the Javascript code for the update function

```
$('#update').click(function(){

gravity = parseFloat(document.getElementById('grav').value);
bounceFactor = parseFloat(document.getElementById('bounce').value);

document.getElementById('setgrav').value = gravity;
document.getElementById('setbounce').value = bounceFactor;

ball = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,

    radius: 15,
    color: "red",

    // Velocity components
    vx: 2,
    vy: 1,

    draw: function() {

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
    }
};


update();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The controls of the form have no value (=== undefined) at the start, so when you update, you let one/several undefined values leak through your code. As you might know, this won't break the program, it will just cease the display in this case.

Two fixes :
• Initialize your controls so they have a valid value. It will also help the user to know about the order of magnitude of the values.
• Update the variables values only after making some basic validation.

```
function getValue(ctrlId) {
   return document.getElementById(ctrlId).value;
}

function isValidNumber ( val ) { return !isNaN(+val); }

function update() {
   var newGravity = getValue( 'grav' );
   if (isValidNumber ( newGravity ) ) gravity = newGravity ;
   //... same for other values.
}
```